# Clickable Image in Header

Tags: css, hyperlink, header, styles, clickable

I've been trying to insert a clickable image into the header to sit on the right bottom. I've been scouring your past questions, and have gotten this far by navigating what is already posted. However, I can get either the style to work with this code without correct linkage:

```
header {

 <style> 
 div#button 
     {
     position:relative;
    align:right;
    top:111px;left:640px; margin:0;width:100%;
    padding-bottom:25px;
   }

</style> 

***position is right, but linkage is wrong***
<div id="button">
  <a href="0379a5a.netsolhost.com/wordpress1/products/products-page/" >  
<img src="http://0379a5a.netsolhost.com/wordpress1/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/shop_now2.png" height="80.5x" width="163.5px" 
<div style="float:right;margin-top: 111px; margin-right: 50px; padding-bottom:16px;"

/></a>
</div>
```

But The link will not work. I can get the link to work, but then the style goes away with this code:

```
 <style> 
 div#shop_now_button 
     {
     position: relative;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 111px;
    margin-left: 640px; 
    margin-right: 50px;

    width:100%;
    padding-bottom:25px;
   }

</style> 


<div id="shop_now_button">
<div style="float:right;margin-top: 111px; margin-right: 50px; padding-bottom:16px;">   
<a s href="http://0379a5a.netsolhost.com/wordpress1/product/products-page/" target="_blank"> 
<img src="http://0379a5a.netsolhost.com/wordpress1/wp- content/uploads/2013/07/shop_now2.png" 
 height="80.5px" 
  width="163.5px"  
 float="right" 
 margin-top="111px" 
 margin-right="50px" 
 padding-bottom="16px" /> 
  </div>
```

I just wish I knew what was going on. I've been trouble shooting for hours now... (I apologize if its a simple solution--I'm new at this)  this is my vanity domain...  http://0379a5a.netsolhost.com/wordpress1/

Comment: Please add a [jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Sorry, but this code is a total disaster. Try double checking your syntax for starters.

Comment: `top` and `left` are not the same as `margin-top` and `margin-left`

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
.header {position: relative;}
.header img {positon: absolute; bottom: 0; right: 0;}
```